# How to change layout of profile2 page?

Tags: hooks, users, theming

I have no experience with php and I've been trying for hours to alter the HTML of a profile 2 (module which extends core profile functionality) page. How can I do this?

Ideally I'd like it so I can just alter the page and add things like:

```
<div>
    <?php print $name ?>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the **Profile2 Page** module in the modules list page.

Then you go to `modules/profile2` and copy `profile2.tpl.php`, paste it into your template folder and there you can customize as you want using...

```
print render($content['YOUR_FIELD']);
```

...or other variables you want.